# not able to connect to rds from local machine

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I am trying to deploy rds instance with MySQL engine using rds. The database subnet group is in public subnet.

I have performed the following checks:
- The security group is allowed public access on port 3306
- Telnet command successfully on endpoint URL on 3306 port

Configuration as below:

[image: RDS configuration]

Security group:
[image: RDS security group]

Logging details:

```
anhs-MBP:mykeys anhtrang$ telnet database-1.c9nddsynmhxo.us-east-2.rds.amazonaws.com 3306
Trying 3.130.77.228...
Connected to ec2-3-130-77-228.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
N
5.7.22-log
*!qV/yIp1Blwamysql_native_password
```

Trying to connect to rds using console

[image]

Comment: You have a space between the host and the port in the URL field (`.com :3306`)

Comment: @Paulpro removed space, same issue.
`Connection to dev-mysql-rds failed.
[08001] Could not create connection to database server. Attempted reconnect 3 times. Giving up.`

Comment: It is best not to allow access to the RDS instance from 0.0.0.0/0. Either specify the IP address of the machine on the internet that needs access, or if that is dynamic, create an EC2 instance and specify that instance's security group as the `Source` to allow. Also, although you hid the instance name in the first screenshot, you forgot to do that for all the others. (Although it would have been very difficult to guess there was a space in there if you had hidden it )

Comment: @Wodin  this is just for test and learning, quick setup only.
In production, its definitely serious security concern and anti security practices

Comment: @JoeyTrang I don't know what software that is. Do you get any more info by clicking on Troubleshooting?

Comment: @Wodin I am using Intelj plugins to connect to RDS, seems having problem with this plugign.

I am able to connect it from `mysqlsh` cli tool is the best :)

Comment: According to Google, it seems MySQL error 08001 has something to do with a bad MySQL driver. e.g. "And the SQL State code is 08001. The reason for this error is that your MySQL JDBC jar file version do not match the MySQL database server version."

Comment: @Wodin  appreciate for your googling :)

Comment: @JoeyTrang See also: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/8.0/en/connector-j-usagenotes-troubleshooting.html

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the problem with MySql driver plugin of `InteliJ`

I am able to connect to rds instance using `mysqlsh` commandline tool.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Since MySQL Server 8.0.11 `caching_sha2_password` is used as default authentication method. Probably IntelliJ MySQL driver do not support this authentication method.
You need to create user with one of the older authentication method, e.g. `CREATE USER xyz@localhost IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'passw0rd'`.

More here https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-user.html and here https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/authentication-plugins.html